# Scraping specific element from Understat.com

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to retrieve specific stat (PPDA) from multiple matchs on this site:

https//understat.com/match/xxxx

I have created the follow to parse the HTML and loop through each match using Python but i am struggling how to extract the specific stat and load it to a csv and to a graph. I am a beginner and any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import csv

for i in range(9577,9807):
    ppda_url = 'https://understat.com/match/' + str(i)
ppda_data = requests.get(ppda_url)
ppda_html = ppda_data.content
xml
soup = BeautifulSoup(ppda_html, 'lxml')
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(ppda_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the 'xxxx' changes per match which is why i used a for loop with range to loop through each match

Comment: you will want to `get` the url *inside* the for loop, otherwise you will only be doing a `get` on the last url created by the loop

Comment: OK I have added the get inside the loop. Now to extract that specific stat is where im struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the data with BeautifulSoup and write it to a CSV file, first find the div element with the text PPDA. Then find the next div element with the class progress-value then the nextdiv element with the class progress-value and get the data from these two last divs. Write it to a csv file like so.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('ppda.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    for i in range(9577,9807):
        ppda_url = 'https://understat.com/match/' + str(i)
        ppda_data = requests.get(ppda_url)
        ppda_html = ppda_data.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(ppda_html, 'lxml')
        ppda = soup.find("div", string='PPDA')
        home = ppda.findNext('div', {'class':"progress-value"})
        print (home.text, home.findNext('div', {'class':"progress-value"}).text)
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow([home.text, home.findNext('div', {'class':"progress-value"}).text])
```

To graph it look at matplotlib for a start.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['HOME', 'AWAY'])
for i in range(9577,9807):
    ppda_url = 'https://understat.com/match/' + str(i)
    ppda_data = requests.get(ppda_url)
    ppda_html = ppda_data.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ppda_html, 'lxml')
    ppda = soup.find("div", string='PPDA')
    home = ppda.findNext('div', {'class':"progress-value"})
    print (home.text, home.findNext('div', {'class':"progress-value"}).text)
    df = df.append({'HOME': float(home.text), 'AWAY' : float(home.findNext('div', {'class':"progress-value"}).text)}, ignore_index=True)
#print (df)
df.to_csv("ppda2.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
df.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Outputs: CSV file and Graph

[image: Graph]

Comment: This is great! it worked. However why with my for loop it does not go through each match to give me the stat in my range i mentioned? so far with this it only gives me the match with id 9806.

Comment: Sorry the  indentation got messed up by the editor it is fixed now

Comment: Ok thats great! i forgot to mention i would need to add teams associated to the stat. I assume its the same but the string = "TEAMS" and I would use the find next to go through both DIV classes?

Comment: for the teams use home = soup.find("div", {'class':'roster-home'}).findNext('h3').text and 
    away = soup.find("div", {'class':'roster-away'}).findNext('h3').text

Comment: If i use home to find the teams  i would need to change the home variable for the PPDA stat correct?

Comment: Ok I will attempt this. I assume I will need to add 2 more arguments in the graph to display team names as well? my variable were "hometeam" and "awayteam"

Comment: yes but there is not much room to display all the data on one graph you may be better splitting it into a number of graphs

Comment: OK I will split them up as there is too much data to display. Now I will attempt to include home team and away team names along with the title for the graph. The DF is displaying the game number where Im attempting to implement the actual team name